# Structure of Quotient Ring

Tags: ring-theory

I'm struggling to see what the structure of a quotient ring such as

$$\mathbb Z[i] / (1+i)$$ is. I think it's supposed to be isomorphic to $\mathbb Z / 2\mathbb Z$ but I don't see how.

Can someone give me a hand?

Comment: Have you tried to draw a diagram showing the Gaussian integers with those in the ideal $(1+i)$ highlighted? You should be able to see on it that every element is either in the ideal or just to the right of something that is in the ideal.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* $\mathbb Z[i]$ is an Euclidean ring and $N(1+i)=2$.